# How do I confirm Apache Compile Options

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to compile apache from source but my previous version was downloaded via yum.
But I need to find the options that were previously used to compile apache with so I can use the same options at the point I recompile. Also i want to ensure my config files are keep intact at the point I recompile.

Note : I tried the following command but the output didnt help too much ,

```
[root@test httpd-2.2.4]# yumdownloader --source httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository c5-testing is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * fc6-base: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: centos.hyve.com
drivesrvr                                                                              |  951 B     00:00
Enabling epel-source repository
No source RPM found for httpd-2.2.3-5.x86_64
No source RPM found for httpd-2.2.3-83.el5.centos.x86_64
No source RPM found for httpd-2.2.3-82.el5.centos.x86_64
No source RPM found for httpd-2.2.26-1.el5.x86_64
Nothing to download
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: See this question/answer: "yum - list configure flags/options used to compile package" -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44674/yum-list-configure-flags-options-used-to-compile-package

Answer (score 0):

httpd -V shows compile options and exits.

```
httpd -V
```

eg, in my case:

-D APR_HAS_SENDFILE

-D APR_HAS_MMAP

-D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)

-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE

-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE

-D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT

-D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD

-D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS

-D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256

-D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"

-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"

-D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd.pid"

-D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"

-D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"

-D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/httpd/mime.types"

-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"

Comment: thanks but when i check these against the options shown within ./configure -help they at all listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the source rpm and inspect it's contents which will give you the relevant options. For CentOS the easiest thing to do is browse [vault.centos.org](http://vault.centos.org/) for your OS version and download the relevant httpd source rpm. Up to C6.2 the location of the srmps was `os/SRPMS` but 6.3 onwards puts them in `os/Source/SPackages`.

Once you have the srpm you can install it then look in `~/rpmbuild/SPECS/httpd.spec` which should help.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt have apache 2.2.4 which is want i need to upgrade to..

Comment: @felix001: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: @lain : CentOS release 5.10

Comment: @felix001: CentOS 5.10 ships with httpd 2.2.3. Did you compile httpd 2.2.4 yourself ?

Comment: @lain : nope im currently running Apache/2.2.3, but I need to upgrade to 2.2.4

Comment: @felix001: So think about this - you need to inspect the 2.2.3 srpm to get the compile options so you can compile 2.2.4 don't you and th 2.2.3 srpm is on vault.c.o.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12108/discussion-between-felix001-and-iain)